# PDF displayed with Shifted Characters in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, character-encoding

Observe this PDF located here, in Google Chrome specifically:
http://www.saab.org/actuary/exam3/3-sample.pdf

Notice how many of the characters appear to be shifted (this is most noticeable toward the end of the document, in the solutions); a lot of the mathematical formulas have had their typical mathematical symbols (like equals, summation, greek letters, etc.) shifted into some kind of other character set.  I don't know enough about the details of what's going on here, but when I view the PDF in other browsers (like Firefox), it displays correctly.

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening?  Is there anything I can do to get it to display in Chrome correctlY?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Enabling "Disable DirectWrite" on the Chrome Flags page. It might help you out. 
chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write